# Is there a video hosting website I can use to upload a video to use for a background on my site

Tags: video, hosting

Is there a website I can use apart from youtube to upload a video to use as a background for my site, I need the mp4 link.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://vimeo.com/?
They are similar to Youtube and offers you facility to share videos on your website (almost like YouTube).

Comment: Yes, have tried vimeo, but they have some kind of url script that changes the mp4 link every day